# Can IE be considered a reasonable website access test for the .Net framework

Tags: ssl, http, internet-explorer, .net

We are currently updating our SSL cipher settings in order to improve our SSL rating. The changes included the removal of SSL3 and RC4 ciphers. However this appears to have caused problems with some of our users who are still on Win XP (believe it or not) so we had to revert.

Before we make any further changes, we'd like to ask these users to test again.

If the user can to access a website via SSL in Internet Explorer, does this automatically infer that he can access the same website in the .Net framework (System.Net)?

IE uses Wininet. But does the .Net framework also use Wininet?

Comment: I'm torn on whether this should be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: Not really, it is a sysop question more than developers. Most developers will not know even how to make this change. To answer - ask the XP users what IE version they use. Likely they did not even update that one ;)

Comment: Happy to move to stackoverflow if more suited.